# How to check if Variable value is increaseing vb.net?

Tags: vb.net, listview, progress-bar

Hi I have listview and lable ,the lable is showing how many items in the listview 
I want if the lable is increased will show msgbox 
* may be it will increased alot such as 100 or 1 whatever 
* It will execute the command just one if the value is increased 
* it must be execute the msgbox any time if the value is increased 
I'm sorry for my bad language 
thank you

the code :

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    Dim b As String = New WebClient().DownloadString(TextBox2.Text + "/Getinfo.php")
    Dim mc As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(b, "(\w+):")
    For Each x As Match In mc
        Dim infoName As String = x.Groups(1).Value
        Try
            Dim download As String = New WebClient().DownloadString(TextBox2.Text + "/sender/info/" & infoName & "/info.txt")
            Dim f As String() = download.Split(":")
            Dim ls As New ListViewItem
            ls.Text = infoName
            For Each _x As String In f
                ls.SubItems.Add(_x)
            Next
            Dim hTable As Hashtable = New Hashtable()
            Dim duplicateList As ArrayList = New ArrayList()
            Dim itm As ListViewItem
            For Each itm In ListView1.Items
                If hTable.ContainsKey(itm.Text) Then 'duplicate
                    duplicateList.Add(itm)
                Else
                    hTable.Add(itm.Text, String.Empty)
                End If
            Next
            'remove duplicates
            For Each itm In duplicateList
                itm.Remove()
            Next
            ListView1.Items.Add(ls)
            'here I want to excute the command if the value is increased but it's timer and the code will be execute every time 

        Catch

        End Try
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Please include your code that is giving the problem.  What do you expect to happen?  What is actually happening?  Please see [How To Ask A Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sometimes people seem to think that programming exists in a vacuum. Just ask yourself how you would do this if it were a manual process. If it was me, I'd check what the count was before I made any changes and then I'd check again what the count was after making changes and then do something if the numbers were different. Why should it be any different here?

Comment: By the way, as the documentation clearly states, if you're going to be adding multiple items to a `ListView`, you should create all the items first and then add them all in one god with a single call to `AddRange`.

Comment: I try alot but nothing is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the top of your function do

```
Dim oldlength = ListView1.Items.Count
```

At the bottom do

```
If oldlength < ListView1.Items.Count Then
    'here I want to excute the command if the value is increased
End If
```

I'm pretty sure that your `MessageBox` isn't really what you want but a debugging example because you think if you can get the MessageBox at the right time you've solved one of your problems (which is true).